# User name or password is incorrect when performing domain join to Azure VM

Tags: azure-active-directory

1. Installed AAD Domain Services with domain name "mydomain.com"
2. Added verified custom domain "mydomain.com"
3. Made "mydomain.com" primary
4. Created AAD user "admin@mydomain.com"
5. Converted temp password to permanent password
6. Logged into Azure with permanent password
7. Added "admin@mydomain.com" to domain administrators group
8. Ensured VM can see domain services for "mydomain.com"
9. When performing domain join, receive "The user name or password is incorrect"

I've tried the following credential combinations when doing the domain join (username : password)

1. admin : pwd
2. admin@mydomain.com : pwd
3. mydomain.com\admin : pwd
4. mydomain.com\admin@mydomain.com : pwd

None of these work and ultimately give me a lock out indication.  I create additional users to continue trying these steps but nothing is working.

Comment: When I logged in today, what I previously tried yesterday worked.  I wonder if it was because I failed to do the last step specified in this link.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-password-sync

Comment: Since then, I re-created the domain because we didn't want "mydomain.com" to conflict with the web site name. We re-created it with "ad.mydomain.com".  This time I followed the steps outlined in the article and tried to add it to the domain with the "admin@mydomain.com".  It didn't work but I'm going to wait 20 minutes like the article mentioned.  
As long as "admin@mydomain.com" is listed in the domain administrators group (AAD DC Administrators), it should still allow me to perform the domain join even though the domain services name is "ad.mydomain.com" correct?

Comment: If you already add to the AAD DC Admin group, it will work for the new.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last step in the instructions from the link below was missed.  Had to enable password hash synchronization to Azure Active Directory Domain Services and wait about 20 minutes.  All worked correctly after that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-password-sync

Answer (score 0):

The user "admin@mydomain.com" you created must belongs to the Azure AD DC administrators group. Only members of this group have privileges to join machines to the managed domain.

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal).

Comment: I made the mistake of not mentioning that step but they are in the domain administrators group.